# CSS Error de inline-Block no se mantiene el estilo

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap

tengo el código mostrado abajo que me muestra el buscador de bodega mostrado en la imagen(ejemplo 1), sin embargo cuando traigo los  con un ciclo for de php pierde el estilo y queda como el mostrado en la imagen(ejemplo 2)... Que puedo hacer para volver a dejarlo como cuando no uso php?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row-fluid cuadro_buscar_buscar" style="margin: 0px; padding:0px; margin-top:30px;">
    <center>
   <div style=" width:800px; margin-bottom:10px;">
        
          <table border="0">
              <tr class="sin_fondo">
               <td style="width: 33%;"><div style="display: inline-block;"><a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" style=" margin:0px; border-bottom-left-radius:2px; border-top-left-radius:2px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 90px; margin-top:0px; font-size: 12px; margin-bottom:0px;background-color:#28b779"> BODEGA</a><select type="text" style=" margin:0px; width:51%; -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance : none; border: 1px solid #28b779; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius:2px; border-top-right-radius:2px; border-bottom-left-radius:0px;  border-top-left-radius:0px; margin-bottom:0px; text-align:center;" name="buscar_bodega" id="buscar_bodega" onchange="buscador();">
                <?php 
      for ($i=0 ; $i < count($bodegas); $i++) { 

        echo '<option value="'.$bodegas[$i]['idBodega'].'">'.$bodegas[$i]['nombre'].'</option>';
      }?>
                </select></div></td>

                <td style="width: 33%;"><div style="display: inline-block;"><a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" style=" margin:0px; border-bottom-left-radius:2px; border-top-left-radius:2px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 90px; margin-top:0px; font-size: 12px; margin-bottom:0px;background-color:#28b779"> CATEGORÍA</a><select type="text" style=" margin:0px; width:51%; -webkit-appearance: none; -moz-appearance : none; border: 1px solid #28b779; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; border-bottom-right-radius:2px; border-top-right-radius:2px; border-bottom-left-radius:0px;  border-top-left-radius:0px; margin-bottom:0px; text-align:center;" name="buscar_categoria" id="buscar_categoria" onchange="buscador();">
                 <option value="nada">Todos</option>
                 <option value="0">Indumentaria</option>
                    <option value="1">Insumos</option>
                    <option value="2">Materiales de entrenamiento</option>
                    <option value="3">Otros</option>
                </select></div></td>

             <td style="width:34%;"><input name="buscar_nombre" type="text" style="width:96%; background-color:white; border: 2px solid #28b779; border-radius:2px; margin-bottom:0px;" placeholder="Buscar producto" maxlength="149" id="buscar_nombre" onKeyUp="buscador();" ></td>
                <td style="width:40px; cursor:pointer;"> <button class="boton_refresh" onClick="buscador();" style="margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon-refresh"></i></button></td>

                <td style="width:40px; cursor:pointer;"> <button class="boton_refresh" onClick="buscador();" style="margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon-refresh"></i></button></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
              
       </div>

             <br>
             <div style="margin:0px; height:20px;"><img src="img/cargando_buscar.gif" id="cargando_buscar" style=" display:none;">
              <span style="color:#dc4e4e; display:none;" id="error_conexion"><b>Error:</b> conexión a internet deficiente.</span>
              <span style="color:#28b779; display:none;" id="sin_resultados">Busqueda sin resultados.</span>
             </div>
             <br>
     </center>
 </div>
```

Comment: Gracias @JoseManuelMorales el Bootstrap lo carge solo para dar diseño al codigo por aca, pero gracias por estar pendiente :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba cambiando display del bloque 'Bodega' de 'inline-block' a 'inline'.

```
<div style="display: inline;"><a class="btn btn-md btn-primary" style=" margin:0px; border-bottom-left-radius:2px; border-top-left-radius:2px; margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 0px; width: 90px; margin-top:0px; font-size: 12px; margin-bottom:0px;background-color:#28b779"> BODEGA</a>
```

Comment: Perfecto @neollob Mil gracias